# Changing www.sitename.com/administrator

Tags: joomla

How to change `www.sitename.com/administrator` to `www.sitename.com/administratorSr5£d?€-^@L` (or anything similar) in order to make it very very hard for any spiteful person or hacker to reach the backend even if, somehow, he was able to identify the username and password?

Comment: Did you try just renaming the folder? Do you get any errors doing that?

Comment: Renaming the administrator directory will essentially break the back-end of your site. This is not the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Lodder answered the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052940/how-to-rename-the-joomla-administrator-folder.

They recommended the Admin Exile Extension - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/15711

Answer (score 0):

Use Akeeba's Admin Tools (www.akeebabackup.com).

It's free (there is also a paid version, with more resources).

Be sure to use the .htaccess generator from Admin Tools, as it will further protect your website.

Install, go to components => admin tools, then go to "Web Application Firewall, and to "configure WAF". There you should set the "Administrator Secret URL Parameter" to anything you like, preferrably between 10 and 16 characters.

The final URL will be site.com/administrator?your-parameter-here (the ? is mandatory after /administrator).